# Ejecutar accion una vez responda la funcion

Tags: javascript, response

Buen dia a todos, tengo una funcion que la ejecuto una vez reciba el response, como saber que la funcion se ejecuto y poder continuar con el codigo del response, la funcion es actCantonEmpr() un vez cargue necesito continuar con el codigo restante.

```
success: function (data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    actCantonEmpr(json[0].provincia);
                    console.log('El id de la ciudad es... '+json[0].ciudad);
                    nbep.val(json[0].nombre_empr);
                    sgep.val(json[0].slogan);
                    rlep.val(json[0].representante_leg);
                    rcep.val(json[0].ruc_empr);
                    pvep.val(json[0].provincia);
                    cdep.val(json[0].ciudad);
                    drep.val(json[0].direccion_empr);
                    tfep.val(json[0].telefono_empr);
                    crep.val(json[0].correo_empr);
                    $('#id_empresaHidden').val(id);
                }
```

Esto lo necesito porque una vez termine de ejecutar la funcion el sistema pueda ahora si me valide la ciudad de `cdep.val(json[0].ciudad)`;

Comment: Pues estimo que la funcion success debe ser async y pones un await a actcantonemp()

Comment: ¿Y por que no le pasas a la función `actCantonEmpr` también `json[0].ciudad`? Así cuando hace lo que hace (_imagino que carga ciudades_) ya sabe sabe que ciudad debe estar seleccionada. Opciones hay muchas, necesitariamos ver el código de dicha función.

Comment: Pues @Marcos se la pase pero como ejecuta todo en el response y primero lee las provincias me selecciona la primera ciudad y no la que viene con el response de ciudad

Comment: Gracias @Hernán Garcia eso estoy buscando ya que entiendo poco como deberia ser  el async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función como una promesa y utilizar el then.

```
 getPosts().then(r =>{
    console.log("la funcion ha funcionado como esperaba");
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log('Algo salió mal');
  });
```

Comment: Pero en el codigo que escribes donde pongo mi funcion :-(

Comment: getPosts() seria la función

Comment: no funciono actCantonEmpr(json[0].provincia).then(r =>{
                        console.log("la funcion ha funcionado como esperaba");
                    }).catch(() => {
                        console.log('Algo salió mal');
                    });

Comment: getPosts(actCantonEmpr(json[0].provincia)).then(r =>{
                        console.log("la funcion ha funcionado como esperaba");
                    }).catch(() => {
                        console.log('Algo salió mal');
                    });

Comment: no funciono de ninguna de las 2 formas :-(